# Vue.js - Swap one input field with another but keep the same v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select field with a dropdown of predefined values. One of the dropdown values is `Other` and when the user selects `Other`, I want to swap this select field with a text field. Now the tricky part, because I want to keep the logic of the select field's `v-model` (posting data via ajax), the text field is using the same `v-model`.

Conditional statements work just fine, the issue is that the input text gets prefilled with Other (which should be editable) and when I delete this prefilled value, the select field pops back in.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<b-select
  v-if="experience.position != 'Other'"
  v-model="experience.position"
  v-validate="'required'"
  expanded
  :name="'position' + index"
  placeholder="Select a position">
  <option
    v-for="item in workPositions"
    v-bind:key="item.id"
    :value="item">
    {{ item }}
  </option>
</b-select>
<b-input
  v-if="experience.position == 'Other'"
  v-model="experience.position"
  v-validate="'required'"
  :name="'otherPosition' + index"
  placeholder="Position">
</b-input>
```

Comment: whats not working, did you try placing `v-if="experience.position !== 'Other'"` on the select, or do v-else? the only issue your have is when switching back, the model won't match an item in the select which may be tricky to validate other then required

Comment: I've tried with `v-if` on the select and it works, but when I delete the prefilled 'Other' text, I get the select field back.

Comment: yeah sure, also its going to say Other initially, maybe instead use a watcher on `experience.position`, or a computed value to toggle the state.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same model for both `select` and `input` and not have it unaltered when the user selects 'other'.

What I mean by that : you could have the other job appended at the end of `experience.position` (other:theotherjob), and do some complex tricks with `watch` and `computed`. But that would be unnecessarily complex.

I think you should have another variable and merge it with your original form on submit.